# Nodejs Mongoose - Check the array object value exists or not, add a new object to array if not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, arrayobject

Im very new with nodejs. I want to check in mongodb if the value is exist or not, if exist, update linkview, if does not exist i want to push an object into array. Can anyone help me on how to write a statement to check the value is exist or not in db? Please help

So this is `Admin` schema

```
{        
  "_id": "67324b2cc6817758118e9557d8",
  "name": "James",
  "__v": 0,
  "affiliatelink": [
    {
      "storeId": 60014d6e7286763490c3543,
      "storeName": white choc,
      "linkview": 1
    }
  ]
}`
```

and this is my current code.

```
Admin.findById(adminId).then(admin =>{
if(admin){
//if affiliatelink.storeId = storeId(exist)
Admin.update({ _id: adminId, "affiliatelink.storeId": storeId}, {$inc: {"affiliatelink.$.linkview": 1}}, 
 (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
    console.log("error "+err)
    } 
    else {
      //push an object into array
    }

  });
```

i try to do this way just to check the if else statement is working or not. but its not working.

```
const res = await Admin.find({"affiliatelink.storeId":storeId; //use async in function definition
console.log(res);
if (check in res) {
  console.log("item is existed")}
else {
  console.log("item is not existed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your third code snippet, you are doing a find operation which will return an empty array of `[]` which will be considered as true, hence that is the reason why the control is not going inside the else condition.
Use `findOne` instead of `find` (if the storeId is unique) else just check the length of the response of the query if it is greater than or equal to 0.